# Photons that escape the universe

Tags: special-relativity, photons, time, universe

According to my current understanding of special relativity, photons do not experience the passage of time. It is as though the universe is completely 'paused' for them. I know that objects with mass cannot accelerate to the speed of light. But isn't the whole point of relativity to predict the motion of an object from a different frame of reference? The universe also tends to increase its size with time. In that case, consider the following thought experiment:

*Let's go back in time to when the universe was relatively young. There was once a photon which, when created, observed the universe to be completely stationary as it didn't experience the ticking of time. As the time does not tick, the universe doesn't expand (relative to the photon) and instantaneously, it exits the universe.*

So my question is, what part(s) of the above statements is false?

Comment: That you believe the universe was finite at some point when everything we can glean from it leads us to believe it is infinite. Perhaps you have a misunderstanding about early universe cosmology as it is currently understood.

Comment: Try to verify what happens to the time period between two events (seen from your frame of reference) when you move closer and closer to the speed of light

Comment: A photon is not an object. It's an irreversible energy exchange between the electromagnetic field and an external system (like a photomultiplier tube or a CCD or, of we are talking many photons, a solar panel). Energy that never makes it to us can never cause a photon detection. Is a large amount of light generated in the invisible part of the universe "lost to us"? Yes.

Comment: All frames measure all light to travel at $c$, therefore there is no "photon frame" in which any quantum of light travels at $0$. One can discuss the limit as $v \to c$ relative to some massive object(s), but such a frame still measures itself to be exactly $c$ slower than light. *What something experiences* is what an observer in the same rest frame measures. Since there is no such rest frame for a photon, the phrase "what a photon experiences" doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

> ... observed the universe to be completely stationary as it didn't experience the ticking of time ...

This is where your mental image is incorrect. [Proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) along the path of photon in vacuum is zero. This does not mean that the universe is stationary from the "point of view" of a photon (if there is such a thing). It means that for the photon there no time passes between its emission and its absorption. If it makes any sense for the photon to "observe" anything (which I doubt) then the photon would "observe" events in the outside universe all happening simultaneously.